# MediaPlayer definition outside onCreate throws NullpointerException?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, oncreate

I need my MediaPlayer Object to be visible as a class variable rather than local to oncreate.

But when I try to initiate it like this-

```
public class TextAct extends AppCompatActivity
{

    MediaPlayer wavesMp =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.river);//Line 132
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    .
    .
    }
```

This fails with same error as well-

```
public class TextAct extends AppCompatActivity
{

    MediaPlayer wavesMp; //Line 132
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     wavesMp=  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.river);
    .
    }
```

Logcat says-

> Process: com.app24.gg.relaaax, PID: 24202
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity > ComponentInfo{com.app24.gg.relaaax/com.app24.gg.relaaax.TextAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
>   at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
>   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:844)
>   at com.app24.gg.relaaax.TextAct.(TextAct.java:132)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` needs context. And if the `onCreate` method is not called, then `Activity` is not prepared and it's `Context` cannot be used.